# I want to show enable a button on first click and when other button is clicked, then the previously clicked one should be inactive

Tags: android-studio, onclick, visibility, android-imagebutton

I had set images in drawable and tried to set them by using onClickListeners and uing View.VISIBLE and View.GONE but once the button is clicked it becomes active forever whereas i want the previously clicked button to be disabled or inactive when new one is clicked. Please help me out anyone?
XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/miniscrollRelative"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:id="@+id/textViewab"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player"
            android:id="@+id/textViewba"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Your_play.."
            android:id="@+id/textViewca"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/downloads"
            android:id="@+id/textViewda"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/streaming"
            android:id="@+id/textViewea"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonhomea"
            android:src="@drawable/homenew"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButtonda"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonaab"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonaab" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonaa"
            android:src="@drawable/player"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonaab"
            android:src="@drawable/player_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonba"
            android:src="@drawable/mydownload"
            android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonbab"
            android:src="@drawable/download_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonca"
            android:src="@drawable/playlist"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoncab"
            android:src="@drawable/playlist_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonda"
            android:src="@drawable/streaming"
            android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtondab"
            android:src="@drawable/streaming_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/miniscrollRelative"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/send_wishes"
            android:id="@+id/textViewfa"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/hit_parade"
            android:id="@+id/textViewga"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/uzbek_instr"
            android:id="@+id/textViewha"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/your_news"
            android:id="@+id/textViewia"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/extras"
            android:id="@+id/textViewja"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonea"
            android:src="@drawable/wishes"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButtonfa"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoneab"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparadea"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonfa"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparade"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonfab"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparade1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonga"
            android:src="@drawable/instrument"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongab"
            android:src="@drawable/instrument_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonha"
            android:src="@drawable/news"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonhab"
            android:src="@drawable/news_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonia"
            android:src="@drawable/extras"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoniab"
            android:src="@drawable/extras_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolBar"
    android:id="@+id/right" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolBar" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="android.app.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/toolBar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#f2434242"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#f2696868"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutad"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AD"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:background="@drawable/playerbar"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@drawable/minipause"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@drawable/minisound"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                android:layout_weight="0.87"
                android:progress="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar3"
                android:max="200"
                android:thumb="@null"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UZ"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="player"

    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toolBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the java code:

```
public class FragmentForScrollBar extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentforscrollbar,null);

    MyPlayer playerFragment = new MyPlayer();
    fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, playerFragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
    home =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhomea);
    player =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaa);
    playlist =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonca);
    download =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonba);
    stream =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonda);
    wish =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonea);
    hit =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfa);
    instrument =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonga);
    news1 =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonha);
    extras1 =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonia);

    homea =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhomea);
    playera =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaab);
    playlista =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoncab);
    downloada =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonbab);
    streama =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtondab);
    wisha =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoneab);
    hita =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfab);
    instrumenta=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtongab);
    newsa =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhab);
    extrasa =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoniab);

    miniplay= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
minisound= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    final ImageButton bP = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.left);
    final ImageButton bN = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.right);

    miniplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.minipause) {

                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    miniplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.minipause);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    miniplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.miniplay);}
        }});
    bP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           // bP1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            hsv.scrollTo(0, -500);
            //if it's the first/last element you can bPrevoius.setEnabled(false)


        }
    });


    bN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           // bN1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            hsv.scrollTo(500, 0);
//                bN.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);

        }
    });
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Home");
            Fragment Home = new Home();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Home);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            // fragmentTransaction.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            //  t.setText("Player");
      }});
    player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//                player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                playera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            player.setEnabled(true);
            t.setText("Player");
            Fragment Myplayer = new MyPlayer();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Myplayer);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
           // fragmentTransaction.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
//                player.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_active);
//                playera.setImageResource(R.drawable.player);
        }
    });
    }}
```